# I can't solve this 'Uncaught Error...' with responsiveNav.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am experiencing an error with responsive-nav.js which strangely is effecting my thumbnails controls in flexslider. http://aortiz.info/mirophotography/

I checked the console and uncollapsed,

***Uncaught Error: The nav element you are trying to select doesn't exist/ResponsiveNav*** 
[image]

This contains 2 additional errors

error-1b
This error seems to go to this line;

```
 _instance = new ResponsiveNav(el, options);
```

***ResponsiveNav***2
[image]

And this is the final error[image]

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: There are no errors in your console on your webpage. I'm not seeing this error.

Comment: Yeah, not sure if this is why but locally I set up a Error 404 page which causes the error to persist longer in the console. Trying to set one up the 404 PROD...
Thanks for you're insight!

Comment: I'd appreciate any help with this one!

Comment: Hey Donte',
Got the error to show up on PROD. http://mirophotography.aortiz.info/ Just hit the scroll up arrow (make the screen tablet width or smaller), and then hit up any thumbnails below the slider. Thanks for any insight!